# Selenium webdriver with two consecutive alerts

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to test a webpage which has two different alerts with this code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

alert = driver.switch_to.alert
alert.accept()
WebDriverWait(driver, 3) \
    .until(EC.alert_is_present(),
           'Timed out waiting for error alert to appear.')
error_alert = driver.switch_to.alert
```

This worked with Selenium 3.4.3, but after upgrading to 3.14.1, it gives the following error on the `WebDriverWait` line:

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: Timed out waiting for error alert to appear.
```

When I set a breakpoint on this line, I clearly see the expected alert in Mozilla with my own two eyes. (I am using geckdriver to run the tests.)

Any suggestions about what I can do to fix this problem?

Comment: maybe it just takes longer to appear? what if you set timeout to something ridiculous, e.g. 30 sec?

Comment: @KirilS. Even when I set a breakpoint on the wait and inspect variables for 5 mins, it still fails.

Comment: So alert never appears at all? do you set any flags on browser startup?

Comment: @KirilS. I am running the test in Firefox with geckodriver. I see the alert appear, but selenium cannot find it.

Comment: So I think 3 options: 1 - not a real alert (but you say it worked in the past, so unlikely); 2 - bug in geckodriver (quite possible); 3 - incompatibility between driver and your browser version. Maybe enable logs and see more details on what it says.

Comment: @KirilS. #2 seems probable. Along those same lines, another possibility is  a bug in selenium itself that hasn't caught up to the most recent update of geckodriver.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, if a bug in geckodriver or compatibility between selenium and geckodriver is suspect, may be you should give chrome a try to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

If the alerts appear immediately, one after another, like this:

```
alert('foo');
alert('bar');
```

... and you have control over server-side JavaScript code, you should separate them, for example like this:

```
alert('foo');
setTimeout(function(){alert('bar');}, 500);
```

This way WebDriver will be able to differentiate between those alert boxes.

Comment: There is no JavaScript on the server here.  And the webpage works as expected. The question here is how to modify the Selenium tests to test the functioning webpage.

Comment: Well, the web page I tested also worked as expected. I was unable to test two consecutive alerts because Selenium went into some kind of a dead loop, perhaps because of how geckodriver is written, perhaps not. I was able to change JS on the server in the way I described and after this I was able to catch both of those alerts in my selenium code.